# Texture blends into one single color

Tags: c++, textures, directx11, hlsl

It looks like that it's being sampled from the least detailed MIP level, at least RenderDoc sees the texture as it should be, and what the actual texture looks like is the same as MIP 9th. I'm using DirectXTex, so I think the shader resource view should be correct.

```
    DirectX::ScratchImage* pImageData = new DirectX::ScratchImage();
    LoadFromDDSFile(path.c_str(), DirectX::DDS_FLAGS_NONE, nullptr, *pImageData);
    const DirectX::TexMetadata& textureMetaData = pImageData->GetMetadata();
    const DirectX::Image* image = pImageData->GetImage(0, 0, 0);
    DirectX::CreateShaderResourceView(
        GetDevice(gfx),
        image, textureMetaData.mipLevels,
        textureMetaData,
        &pShaderResourceView);
```

and the sampler is

```
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
    samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC;
    samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 4;
    samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    samplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(GetDevice(gfx)->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &pSamplerState));
    pImageData->Release();
```

then

```
    GetContext(gfx)->PSSetShaderResources(0u, 1u, &pShaderResourceView);
    GetContext(gfx)->PSSetSamplers(0u, 1u, &pSamplerState);
```

Input layout might be relevant

```
    const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC> inputElemDesc =
    {
        {"Position", 0u, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0u, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,
        D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0u},
        {"TexCoordinate", 0u, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0u, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,
        D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0u},
        {"Normal", 0u, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0u, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,
        D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0u}
    };
```

Vertex shader

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 position : Position;
    float2 texCoord : TexCoordinate;
    float3 normal : Normal;
};

struct PSstruct
{
    float4 PosH : SV_Position;
    float3 PosW : Position;
    float3 NormalW : Normal;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD;
};
PSstruct main(VertexIn vin)
{
    PSstruct vout;

    vout.Tex = vin.texCoord;;
    return vout;
}
```

pixel shader. I removed light related code, I'm fairly sure that here it's not important. And I temporarily disabled it

```
Texture2D cubeTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState cubeSample : register(s0);

struct PSstruct
{
    float4 PosH : SV_Position;
    float3 PosW : Position;
    float3 NormalW : Normal;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};
float4 main(PSstruct pin) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 texColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    texColor = cubeTexture.Sample(cubeSample, pin.tex);
    float4 litColor = texColor;
    return litColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Texture coordinates were wrong. The ones that I was sending to vertex buffer.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how you diagnosed that the coordinates you were using were wrong, and how you corrected them.

Comment: In my google journeys I noticed that I'm suppose to give it's texture coordinates, while I got the impression it will make them itself. So I was sending zeroes. It's embarasing really...